# Subgroups and Identity

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $H$ and $K$ be a finite subgroups of a group $G$ whose orders are relatively prime, that is, $\gcd(|H|,|K|) = 1$. Show that $H ∩K=\{e\}$, where $e$ is the identity in $G$.

I really have a very small knowledge regarding abstract algebra, since I've only explored this topic today, and I have to answer this before the next morning. Hope someone can answer this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with Lagrange's theorem?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: suppose $x\in H\cap K$ and consider $\langle x\rangle$ the subgroup generated by $x$. What does Lagrange's theorem say about $|\langle x\rangle|$ and $|H|$? Then…

Answer (score 0):

Consider the left cosets of $H$ in $G$, i.e. for each $a\in G$, $$aH = \{ah:h\in H\}. $$
If $aH$ and $bH$ are two left cosets of $H$, then the map $f:aH\to bH$ with $f(x)=ba^{-1}x$ is bijective (as $g(y)=ab^{-1}y$ is an inverse). Since the left cosets partition $G$, it follows that each left coset of $H$ has precisely $|H|$ elements (since $H=eH$ is a left coset of itself). It follows that $$|G| = [G:H]\cdot|H|, $$
where $[G:H]$ is the number of left cosets of $H$ in $G$. Therefore $|H|$ and $|K|$ divide $|G|$, and further, $|H\cap K|$ divides $|H|$ and $|K|$. From here we can conclude.